# Querying data behind Daily Utilization Summary

Tags: blueprism

I have a daily utilization graph setup on Blueprism. I am trying to query this data from the database but data doesn't seem to match? Even a select * doesn't seem to bring back matching numbers

My Query is

```
Select reportdate, Sum(hr0 + hr1 + hr2 + hr3 + hr4 + hr5
+ hr6 + hr7 + hr8 + hr9 + hr10 + hr11 + hr12 + hr13 + hr14 
+ hr15 + hr16 + hr17 + hr18 + hr19 + hr20 + hr21 + hr22 + hr23) 
from dbo.BPMIUtilisationMonthly
group by reportdate;
```

If I add up all the hour columns for a particular date it is not the same as on the graph.

I am trying to bring back the amount of usage the resources have had by week. This is not an option through the Blueprism reporting capabilities (As far as I can see).

[image]

Comment: *"[The] data doesn't seem to match"* - *what* doesn't it match?

Comment: @esqew Updated Question!

Comment: What version of Blue Prism is this?

Comment: It's 6.3, apologies never saw your comment

Answer (score 0):

A trace of the queries run against the backing database shows that this tile relies on the Blue Prism-provided stored procedure `BPDS_DailyUtilisation`.

I would imagine the stored procedure itself is legally protected from being shared here, but if you have Blue Prism installed it's trivial to use a SQL Server management utility to view the code that backs up this stored procedure.

Comment: How would I go about getting the data I need?

Comment: @E_McAndrew you haven't specified the data you specifically need (unless I'm missing that portion), but you could dump the results of the subquery to a temporary table and query against that to filter for the data you need.

Comment: Apologies, you're correct. I have updated my question now.